# Why am I getting the following error on compilation: "cannot find symbol - method toArray()" (java)?

Tags: java

Here's the relevant lines of code:

```
HashSet<Integer> products = new HashSet<Integer>();  
...  
Integer[] arrProducts = prodDigs.toArray();`
```

Any idea why I'm getting the error stated in the question?

I'm using BlueJ as my IDE if it's at all relevant.

Comment: What is the type of prodDigs?

Comment: this code is not enough to identify the issue. proDigs may not be created on it may not visible to your code block

Comment: Is it a typo? should it be `products.toArray()` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. It should indeed have been `products.toArray()`. As for prodDigs, it's an int[] and should not be referred to in this line. Lesson learned: don't write code after midnight.

Answer (score 1):

With your little decription, I could guess you want to convert hash set to array using to Array():

To convert your hash set to integer array you can use :

```
Integer[] arrProducts = products.toArray(new Integer[products.size()]);
```

Comment: It would be nice to explain, first the typo, then why you use `AbstractCollection.toArray(T[])` instead of `AbstractCollection.toArray()`.

Comment: Ah, found the typo - that's not in my code, that's a result of being a first-time poster on Stack Overflow, and as such, messing up the formatting @AxelH

Comment: Although yes, I would like an explanation as to why use toArray(T[]) instead of toArray(). I think I've figured it out after reading the documentation now that I know that you should do that in my case (it's because I've instantiated my HashSet, isn't it?)

Comment: @AxelH found the typo, and I can't make an edit to my comment yet, but must leave for class before I'll be able to. That's why you shouldn't code at 1 AM.

Comment: Don't worry @ThomasRiley , those remarks were addressed to Adya to improve the answer. Not a remark on your code ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just try Java 8 Way

Option 1

```
Integer arrProducts[]=products.stream().toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Option 2

```
Integer arrProducts[]=products.stream().toArray(n->new Integer[n]);
```

Comment: Would you mind offering an explanation of why this works? I read the stream() method on the documentation for java.util.Collection, but am having trouble figuring out exactly what it does.